Ungrouping data by indexing sub-objects and stacking in pandas
I have data that operates like it has been grouped. My goal is to keep only the most recent date for each name exclusively for location 'Home', in other words I want to know the most recent date that each person was 'Home'.
Dataframe df:
       ID           Date01     Location01 Date02     Location02  Date03     Location03
0      jane         1/01/2023  Home       2/24/2024  Home
1      sarah        2/03/2024  Home        
2      ricardo      2/05/2024  Home       4/28/2024  Office      5/03/2024  Home
3      thomas       3/23/2024  Home         
4      lee          4/01/2024  Home       5/07/2024  Satellite    
5      patrick      1/02/2024  Home
6      anya         3/05/2022  Office     4/19/2024  Home          

I want the output:
       ID           Date      Location
0      jane         1/01/2023 Home
1      jane         2/24/2024 Home  
2      sarah        2/03/2024 Home         
3      ricardo      2/05/2024 Home
4      ricardo      4/28/2024 Office   
5      ricardo      5/03/2024 Home
6      thomas       3/23/2024 Home          
7      lee          4/01/2024 Home   
8      lee          5/07/2024 Satellite     
9      patrick      1/02/2024 Home   
10     anya         3/05/2022 Office    
11     anya         4/19/2024 Home          

So that I can remove all that isn't Location 'Home', and then remove everything except the most recent date per ID, leaving the final output:
       ID           Date      Location
0      jane         2/24/2024 Home    
1      sarah        2/03/2024 Home              
2      ricardo      5/03/2024 Home
3      thomas       3/23/2024 Home              
4      lee          4/01/2024 Home     
5      patrick      1/02/2024 Home     
6      anya         4/19/2024 Home

I think maybe I need to set indexes for the sub-object Dates and stack but I'm pretty stuck. Does anyone have any ideas on where to begin with this?
Thank you!

There is an useful function in pandas 2.2.2 called lreshape for this.
You can do:
locs = df.filter(regex="^Location").columns.tolist()
dates = df.filter(regex="^Date").columns.tolist()
out = pd.lreshape(df, {'Location': locs, 'Date': dates})
out = out[out["Location"].eq("Home")].groupby("ID", as_index=False).agg(max)
print(out)

        ID Location       Date
0     anya     Home  4/19/2024
1     jane     Home  2/24/2024
2      lee     Home  4/01/2024
3  patrick     Home  1/02/2024
4  ricardo     Home  5/03/2024
5    sarah     Home  2/03/2024
6   thomas     Home  3/23/2024


One way of doing this is the following, which consists essentially of transforming the dataframe from wide to long.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': ['jane', 'sarah', 'ricardo', 'thomas', 'lee', 'patrick', 'anya'],
    'Date01': ['1/01/2023', '2/03/2024', '2/05/2024', '3/23/2024', '4/01/2024', '1/02/2024', '3/05/2022'],
    'Location01': ['Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Office'],
    'Date02': ['2/24/2024', None, '4/28/2024', None, '5/07/2024', None, '4/19/2024'],
    'Location02': ['Home', None, 'Office', None, 'Satellite', None, 'Home'],
    'Date03': [None, None, '5/03/2024', None, None, None, None],
    'Location03': [None, None, 'Home', None, None, None, None]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_long = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Date', 'Location'], i='ID', j='visit', sep='')
df_long = df_long.reset_index().dropna()
df_home = df_long[df_long['Location'] == 'Home']
df_home = df_home.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Date'], ascending=[True, False])
df_home = df_home.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep='first')
df_home = df_home.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_home)

which gives
        ID  visit       Date Location
0     anya      2  4/19/2024     Home
1     jane      2  2/24/2024     Home
2      lee      1  4/01/2024     Home
3  patrick      1  1/02/2024     Home
4  ricardo      3  5/03/2024     Home
5    sarah      1  2/03/2024     Home
6   thomas      1  3/23/2024     Home

